# CrmServiceClient reuse or connection pooling in Web Api project

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to understand how to use CrmServiceClient of the CRM SDK in a Web Api project and want to confirm if my understanding is correct.

Is it true that CrmServiceClient implements connection pooling? If so, is it valid to simply create a new instance per web-request as the overhead of creating a new connection will be mitigated by CrmServiceClient?

Or should I use a single instance of CrmServiceClient throughout the entire application? I don't think this works because my understanding is it is not thread safe and eventually the connection will close (I think).

Answer (score 1):

It says in the [documentation for CrmServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.aspx):

> **Thread Safety**
>   Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type **are thread safe**. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

(Emphasis my own)

I certainly use one static instance of CrmServiceClient throughout my applications and have never experienced an issue.

Comment: It says only public static members are thread safe. When using a CrmServiceClient instance to create an instance of XrmServiceContext would it not result in calls to some of the non-static instance members? Does the connection made by CrmServiceClient not close or timeout after some period of inactivity? My concern is if I reuse it do I need to check somehow if the connection is still open?

Comment: It says all constructors are thread safe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn688177.aspx Check your connection status: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn688177.aspx#Determine

Comment: I believe that IsReady is set to true when the initial connection request is successful. Could it not close/timeout after a successful connection after a long period of time?

Comment: In honesty I don't know for sure. The documentation just says that `IsReady` determines whether the service is ready for requests, it doesn't give specifics. I'm not aware that the service times out, once you've created the connection it's valid until closed/disposed. Unfortunately I don't have any documentation to show you on this.

Answer (score 1):

I found that CrmServiceClient is thread-safe as stated here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688177.aspx: *All the calls to Dynamics 365 using the CrmServiceClient class are thread safe.*

In the application I am working on I have cached a single instance of CrmServiceClient which is used throughout the application. Before using it I check the IsReady property. This single instance is used to instantiate XrmServiceContext instances (in using blocks) throughout the application.

Also, in my tests it appeared connection pooling was not something that was performed by CrmServiceClient. I did a test where I called an API endpoint 100 times and for each call the instantiation time of CrmServiceClient remained mostly the same. I could be wrong but I am thinking it does not perform connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is indeed pooled. It's common to use a single connection throughout an application, but it depends on what you want to accomplish. Adding "RequireNewInstance=True" to your connection string will create a new connection each time it's used. I typically only do this when I'm creating integrations where I need to push more data simultaneously.

Comment: I don't have RequireNewInstance=true and it never seems to pool the connections. Interesting, do you have any sources?